# How to change Next-pwa caching strategy?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-pwa

**Im trying to change Next-Pwa plugin caching strategy from NetworkOnly to CacheFirst for fethcing data.**

[image]

as you can see in image its using Network only for fetching incoming data.

I was searching for any information about how I can do this , but Next-pwa documentation is very poor, and a bunch of links is missing.

I was trying different settings for Next-Pwa plugin I have no clues.

here is my settings

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach as well. The problem is that cache isn't exportable, so we can't modify it that way.

I ended up copying cache.js from NODE_MODULES and I created a new file called runtimeCachingConfig.js. Then I made the changes I needed:

```js
const runtimeCaching = [
  {
    urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.(?:gstatic)\.com\/.*/i,
    handler: 'CacheFirst',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'google-fonts-webfonts',
      expiration: {
        maxEntries: 4,
        maxAgeSeconds: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 365 days
      }
    }
  },
// I left out the majority of the default code for brevity
{
    urlPattern: ({ url }) => {
      const isSameOrigin = self.origin === url.origin
      console.log('bird: Processing URL in cross-origin cache:', url.href);
      return !isSameOrigin
    },
    handler: 'CacheFirst', // changed this
    options: {
      cacheName: 'cross-origin',
      expiration: {
        maxEntries: 32,
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 // 1 hour
      },
      networkTimeoutSeconds: 10
    }
  },
  {

// That didn't catch all the things I needed caching, so I added this:
    urlPattern: /^https:\/\/sample\.website\.net\/items\/.+/i,
    handler: 'CacheFirst',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'Database assets',
      expiration: {
        maxEntries: 64,
        maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 7 days
      }
    }
}

]

module.exports = runtimeCaching;
```

Then I just had to put in into `next.config.js`

```js
const changeRuntimeCaching = require('./src/your/path/runtimeCachingConfig');

const withPWA = require('@ducanh2912/next-pwa').default({
  dest: 'public',
  register: true,
  cacheStartUrl: true, // Maybe this helps?
  cacheOnFrontendNav: true, // Maybe this helps?
  aggressiveFrontEndNavCaching: true, // Maybe this helps?
  workboxOptions: {
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // Set limit to 10 MB
    runtimeCaching: changeRuntimeCaching,
  },
});
```

Please note that I am not using next-pwa because the dev stopped updating it about a year ago before app router became stable. ducanh2912 created a branch and is carrying the project forward:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ducanh2912/next-pwa

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting in next.config.js

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /^https?.*/, // Change the regex to match the routes you want
      handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'http-cache',
        expiration: {
          maxEntries: 100,
          maxAgeSeconds: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
        },
      },
    },
    
  ],
});
```

It doesn't affect the local test. The caching is still network only but it does change when built and deployed. You can see them in the browser developer tool and look under sources - sw.js